# boost 1.47 compile error with non_blocking()

Tags: c++, windows, boost, boost-asio

Can anyone discern what I'm doing wrong here? According to the documentation in 1.47 basic_datagram_socket inherits from basic_socket so the non_blocking() or non_blocking(bool) should be inherited.
Thanks

Error    1    error C2039: 'non_blocking' : is not a member of 'boost::asio::basic_datagram_socket'    c:\DEV\projects\topoTest\topoTest\multiReceiver.cpp    129

This is the call.
socket_.non_blocking(true);

and the socket is defined as follows within a class:

boost::asio::ip::udp::socket socket_;

Comment: please post the entire code you use to reproduce this problem, there is nothing obviously wrong with the limited code you have posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The member function `boost::asio::ip::udp::socket::non_blocking()` appears to be new in 1.47. Either it doesn't actually exist in 1.47 or you're actually using an older header.  I'd suggest finding the `<boost/asio/basic_datagram_socket.hpp>` header that's being included to see if it actually has that member function as part of the `basic_datagram_socket` class.  If not, you can always do it the old way like Steve Townsend said in his answer.

I just downloaded Boost 1.47 and found that `basic_datagram_socket` inherits `non_blocking()` from `basic_socket`.  It looks to me like you don't actually have Boost 1.47.

Comment: Sean, thanks your answer set me in the right direction. I do have 1.47, but I somehow didn't remove the reference to 1.46 which was ahead of the 1.47 reference in the include path.  So the whole reason for this was with 1.47 I thought I'd now be able to return immediately from the async_receive_from if nothing to read with a would_block error, but so far the async_receive_from blocks until there's a datagram to return, even with non_blocking set to true. So I'm a bit stumped at this point. Will analyse further.

Comment: @Al `async_receive_from` always returns immediately, you likely are encountering other behavior. I suggest asking a new question.